# JQuery Issue - Logo doesn't show up until scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, header, scroll

I implemented a jquery that changes the header when we scroll - http://www.usher1f.org/.  It's working very well except that the big logo on the left side does not show up when we first visit the page until we start scrolling.  I want the logo to show up right away when first visit the page.  How can we fix this issue?

Comment: Hey there, you have to abstract out some code to show us how we can help you and in turn, possibly help others. A link might not be valid in future, making this question otherwise useless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because your logo div needs to start out with class "large".

```
<div id="logo" class="large"></div>
```

instead yours starts with no class specified, and your scroll javascript appends one, but initially there is no class until someone scrolls so your logo has no height or width.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much for finding the cause of the problem!  It's fixed.